# Records with DateFrom and DateTo - date range optimalization

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

Here is a reproducible example of what I want to achieve. Basically I have a datefrom column, dateto column and some value columns. Data in table:

| Name | DateFrom | DateTo | Role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2000-01-01 | 2001-11-22 | driver |
| John | 2000-05-01 | 2001-10-22 | driver |
| John | 2002-12-01 | 2002-12-12 | driver |
| John | 2000-12-01 | 2005-12-12 | teacher |
| John | 2000-09-01 | 2001-12-01 | driver |
| John | 1999-12-01 | 2000-01-01 | driver |
| George | 1999-12-01 | 2000-01-01 | driver |

I need to merge overlapping ranges within the same Name and Role, to get this output:

| Name | DateFrom | DateTo | Role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1999-12-01 | 2001-12-01 | driver |
| John | 2002-12-01 | 2002-12-12 | driver |
| John | 2000-12-01 | 2005-12-12 | teacher |
| George | 1999-12-01 | 2000-01-01 | driver |

Thank you

Comment: It usually helps if you also explain how/what you want to achieve in words. Otherwise it becomes a find waldo game

Comment: This is not a free code writing service "I need xxx" is not a request for help, its your requirements. I suggest you have a code, and politely ask for help when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is a classic *gaps-and-islands* problem.** There are many different approaches.

A common solution, if somewhat inefficient, is to use `LAG` and/or `LEAD` to identify the beginning of each group of rows, then assign group numbers using a conditional windowed `COUNT`. Then simply group by the group number

```sql
WITH NewIntervals AS (
    SELECT *,
      isNew = CASE WHEN LAG(DateTo) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DateFrom) >= DateFrom
                    AND LAG(Role)   OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DateFrom) = Role
                   THEN NULL ELSE 1 END
    FROM YourTable t
),
Groups AS (
    SELECT *,
      grp = COUNT(isNew) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DateFrom ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM NewIntervals
)
SELECT
  Name,
  Role = MIN(Role),
  DateFrom = MIN(DateFrom),
  DateTo = MAX(DateTo)
FROM Groups
GROUP BY
  Name,
  grp;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/RVYxm-ex)

Comment: Since you mentioned it, is there a more performant solution?

Comment: Basically involves removing rows using a `WHERE` and using windowed aggregates to calculate the final results, without introducing a sort into the query plan. I don't recall the exact details but you can google it maybe. Itzik Ben Gan has a whole series on this type of problem.

Comment: @DaleK, this looks like a [Packing Intervals](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/new-solution-packing-intervals-problem) problem and Itzik Ben-Gan wrote a very detailed article about it.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Itzik has a whole series of articles on it in various blogs, and even a few chapters in his book.

Comment: Thank you Chalieface very much. You save a lot of my time. I've tweaked the code a bit to suit my needs.
change #1:
'LAG(DateTo)' changed to 'LAG(DATEADD(d, 1, DateTo))' - to cover case:
record 1: dateTo='2000-12-31'
record 2: dateFrom='2001'-01-01' - now will be merged

change #2:
'ORDER BY DateFrom' changed to 'ORDER BY Role, DateFrom' to cover case:
record 1: John; driver; 2000-04-01; 2000-10-01
record 2: John; driver; 2000-10-01; 2000-12-01
record 3: John; teacher; 2000-08-01; 2002-12-01

Comment: @DaleK Something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/qmoj6ShO as you can see there are no sorts